# RegEx needed to match number to 2 decimal places,Optional $ and Comma

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking for some regex that can extract me values as given below.

```
New Balance $13,093.75 Old balance -121.33

Expected output: 

13,093.75

-121.33
```

I tried using `"^[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}$|[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}[^0-9]"`, but no match found.

Comment: Try following : @"[-+]?\d{1,3}(,\d{1,3})*\.?\d*";

Comment: Try your expression on [http://regex101.com/](http://regex101.com/) and see description. The characters `.` and `$` have a meaning in RegEx and you use them not in a correct way. See the description on the page. P.S. You do not have the `-` character in the number.

Comment: Don't use ^ which means it appears at beginning of the expression.

Comment: An abridged version of my former solution for this scenario - [`[-+]?[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)*(?:\.[0-9]+)?`](https://regex101.com/r/vj0ce6/1) If `(?:\.[0-9]+)?` is replaced with `\.[0-9]+` only floats will be matched.